How do emulate the gradle task "connectAndroidTest" on the command line
I am working on a simple bt project for android. I have been using Android Studio to develop my test and through this IDE, i can run this test no problem with gradle.
The issue is i need to run this test on the adb command line and i cannot for the life of me determine how to do it.
Some notes:

Android 10
The apk installs fine
I have an empty application, just the test
The test is stores like so app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/bt_tests/BluetoothInstrumentedTest.java

Any Help at all would be appreciated!
from my research, i should run this:
adb shell am instrument -w -e class 'com.example.bt_tests.BluetoothInstrumentedTest' com.example.bt_tests/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
But it returns with this error:
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.example.bt_tests/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
        at com.android.commands.am.Instrument.run(Instrument.java:514)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:196)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:80)INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.example.bt_tests/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}

INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService       at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:56)

        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:50)INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1

        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:338)

